# Comparison of topologies in the real line

Tags: general-topology

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the topology given by the base $\beta=\left\lbrace [a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}\mid a\in \mathbb{Q},\ b\in\mathbb{I}\right\rbrace$. I want to compare this topology with the usual one, and I know that $\tau_{\beta}\nsubseteq \tau_{usual} $, since $[a,b]\in \tau_{\beta}$ but $[a,b]\notin \tau_{usual},$ but I cannot make my head around the other inclusion $\tau_{usual}\subset \tau_{beta} .$

I suspect that indeed it does verify. It's obvious that if we can find, given an open $(a,b)\in\tau_{usual},$ a sequence of rationals converging to $a$ ($a$ can be rational or not), and a sequence of irrationals converging to $b$ ($b$ can be as well rational or not), the inclusion indeed holds, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Any ideas? Is my suspicion correct?

Comment: What is $\mathbb I$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}, $ the irrationals

Comment: $\Bbb P$ is a more common notation for the irrationals.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: that's interesting: I've never seen that usage of $\Bbb{P}$ (which is always the powerset operator for me, but I have occasionally seen used it for the set of prime numbers). Can you point me at an example, please. Do you know what the mnemonic intention behind using $\Bbb{P}$ for the irrationals is?

Comment: ... and I forgot the projective spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a,b\in\mathbb R$ and $a<b$, let $m=\frac{a+b}2$. Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a decreasing sequence of rational numbers from $(a,m)$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$ and let $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an increasing sequence of irrational numbers from $(m,b)$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=b$. Then$$(a,b)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\overbrace{[a_n,b_n]}^{\phantom\beta{}\in{}\beta}$$and therefore $(a,b)\in\tau_\beta$.

Comment: Could you explain more in detail what the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is and how to you know it is rational?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of rational numbers because I decided that it would be.

Comment: Ok, so you are using that such sequence exist, not constructing it, I get it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes. For instance, I take $a_1\in(a,\min\{a+1,m\})\cap\mathbb Q$, $a_2\in\left(a,\min\left\{a+\frac12,a_1\right\}\right)\cap\mathbb Q$, $a_3\in\left(a,\min\left\{a+\frac13,a_2\right\}\right)\cap\mathbb Q$, and so on.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

If $(a,b)$ is an interval in the usual topology and $a < x < b$, we can find a rational $q$ and an irrational $r$ such that $a < q < x < r < b$, because both rationals and irrationals are dense in the usual topology and then 
$$x \in [q,r] \subseteq (a,b)$$ so all points of $(a,b)$ are interior points of $(a,b)$ in $\tau_\beta$. So $(a,b) \in \tau_\beta$ and as this holds for the base of the usual topology, $\tau_{\text{usual}} \subseteq \tau_\beta$.

Comment: Not the prove that I was looking for, but still very interesting, thank you.